# Magento Clone for Offsite Work

Tags: magento-1.9, backup

I'm working on making changes to an existing Magento site, but I don't want these changes to be 'live' since it could affect user interaction while changes are being made. `I'd like to make all these changes and then make them 'live' once everything is done. I've been doing some research and think the best way for this is to host the site offline, make the changes, and re-upload those files that were changed.`

**Does anyone have a better solution / experience doing this?**

Comment: Do you already use a version control system, such as git? What sort of changes are you making?

Comment: copy your magento to another instance, folder, virtual domain.etc. or to your local laptop, use git and push your code to github and from github pull to dev, and after testing to live...

Comment: I don't use anything like GIT but I certainly can if that's the best way to do it. I have taken the site over from another developer doing work (and messing it up). Most of the changes however are just style sheet changes, but the client is concerned about these changes being done live and causing a disruption to the site, which is understandable.

Comment: @ADM Okay, I have saved the files from Magento locally onto my computer, downloaded GitHub, created a repository, put the Magento files into that folder (they now appear in GitHub) but how do I 'pull to dev' ?  When I click on 'pull' it comes up 'failed to get HEAD'.

Comment: UPDATE: I actually just ended up doing it through MAMP in the end. Seems to be working fine!